# Update value on insert into table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am working with SQL Server - on inserting into a table, I have a unique constraint on a table column `id`. There is a possibility that when inserting, the value going into the `id` column is `0`. This will cause an error.

Is it possible to update this `id` to another value during the insert if the `id` value is 0? This is to prevent the error and to give it a valid value.

Possibly a trigger?

Comment: set the default binding value to that column from database and try...

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is one way, but you may want to use a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX, not as a table constraint) to ignore zero value. This way, you don't have to worry about what value to put there

Alternatively, if you want to populate it from another column, you can have a computed column with a unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE whatever 
    ADD ComputedUniqueCol = CASE WHEN Id = 0 THEN OtherCol ELSE Id END
```

Comment: 0 isnt a valid value so want to catch on insert.

Comment: @amateur: what is a valid value then?

Answer (score 0):

If that's your primary key you can specify it as IDENTITY. Then it should generate a value for itself based on seed and increment (the default is seed=1 and default=1) so you don't have to worry about it.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

create an "instead of" trigger and check for the value on the ID.

```
CREATE trigger checkID
on YOUR_TABLE
instead of insert
as
begin
    declare @id int
    select @id=id from inserted
    if (@id==0) begin
        --DO YOUR LOGIC HERE AND THEN INSERT
    end else begin
        insert into DESTINATION_TABLE (VALUES)
        SELECT VALUES FROM INSERTED
    end
end
```